# What URL to enter to get phpmyadmin database as json

Tags: mysql, json, phpmyadmin

I recently installed xampp on a server and set up a database on some tables.

So if my url to view my tables is

http://nameofserver.com/phpmyadmin

And my database is called nameofdatabase

What URL would I need to enter to view my database in json format?

Answer (score 0):

To export JSON data from phpMyAdmin, enter your database or table. Then look for the "Export" tab along the top row of menu buttons. Select "JSON" from the "Format" dropdown. Feel free to pick other export options or just accept the defaults.